# mfc c++ set HWND address of another application through edit control

Tags: c++, mfc, hwnd

I know how to get and set the handle of another applications window in the code, but I don't know how to set the applications handle at runtime through an edit control. the problem is is that I have to keep compiling my application every time I want to use it, because the handle of the window in application 2 is dynamic.

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: i don't really see how it's difficult to understand, but i guess not everyone will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find current HWND of application window you are interested in, you can enumareate windows using `EnumWindows`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

or maybe easier is to use `FindWindow`, if you know its name/class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

you can also use `GetWindow` to iterate windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

...lots of possibilities